# Question edited unacceptably?

Tags: discussion

So, apparently a question I spent a fair bit of time answering ( [What is the octet mode in TFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42941335/what-is-the-octet-mode-in-tftp/42941493) ) got edited in some unacceptable way and is now locked.  The locked link said come to meta for more information.

It doesn't look like I can see the edit history to see what happened.  Is that no longer possible or am I just missing where?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42941335/revisions

Comment: Their comment on revision 4 is quite informative...

Comment: Does clicking on the *edited X hours ago* above the editor not take you to the revision history?

Comment: It does.  It guess that just wasn't obvious to me (at least before breakfast :)

Comment: It seems like the user's got his account hacked and they're trying to ruin his reputation.

Comment: @Bugs: Pahahaha :D

Comment: @TankorSmash: It's possible. We also see sometimes that users try (in vain) to hide the fact they asked a question from their teacher/employer. This does seem like a particularly failed attempt at that, though, so I'd wager you're right in this case. Either way, the mods & devs will figure it out.

Comment: @NathanOliver: To be fair, if Stack Exchange refuses to use _underline_ styling for links then this is what happens!

Comment: @TankorSmash: Well, okay, looking at the profile.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188538/opencv-error-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgfortran-so-1-cannot-op#comment65725971_39188538 and https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39188538/revisions rev 2 ... maybe more of a personality problem than a security problem.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition maybe not the most mature user, but editing a question into something completely different looks like homework hiding to me.  Especially since the original has a homework smell to it.  The garbage at the end could be the OP hoping his defacement will result in the question getting deleted to hide his sins more completely.

Comment: @DanNeely: For a moment, I thought you were saying "[I'm] not the most mature user, but..."! lulz Anyway, yes, that's the sort of thing I was referring to.

Comment: Umm, OK, not an improvement.  I'm just going to go with "inside joke I am not hip enough for"

Comment: @BoundaryImposition  Sorry about that, I'd edit to clarify that I was talking about the person screwing with his question if I could.

Comment: @JohnHascall both of those blocks of gibberish were included in the rolled back edits that got the question locked.

Comment: [For your amusement, here is all his revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6334139/mybushisaneonjungle?tab=activity&sort=revisions).

Comment: @DanNeely: Heh, don't worry about it, I was mostly joking about the fact that apparently I can't read :)

Comment: @NathanArthur: That's impressive. I think it's clear this individual needs a time-out of some kind. Actually I'm surprised he hasn't been 1-repped by now.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition He is temporarily banned now.

Comment: @TuringTux: Looks like my flag was useful. :) My 1,001st, actually!

Comment: @NathanArthur I wouldn't like to find amusement by what could be a medical condition. This harms our reputation as a community and professional field.

Comment: @JoeFrambach Eh, I find the twisted sense of humor combined with wanting to avoid being caught getting other people to do his homework scenario more likely. ;)

Comment: @JoeFrambach I have no cue how (possible, though highly unlikely) "medical condition" is any kind of deterrent to humor. This human actually seem to have a very acute sense of what we look for, or actually don't look for, in revisions, and is successfully trolling you. People are people, and "medical condition" is no excuse for not being picked on.

Comment: It does seem sad/wrong to me that people are "piling on" his question (-9 at the moment) because of the later shenanigans -- I thought the original question was a decent one worth a decent answer ...

Comment: @JohnHascall - There was a two-hour window (between 04:13 UTC and 06:10 UTC) during which the edit vandalism had not yet been undone. It's possible that many/most of the downvotes happened during that time -- and people who downvote a question rarely come back to see if it's been fixed later on.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can click on the edited X hours/days ago button to look at revisions. [This is what that links to](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42941335/revisions)

It's locked in the state it was when you answered it as the OP tried repeatedly to change it into an entirely different question to which your answer would not apply. That wouldn't have been fair to you, would it?

There's nothing you really need to do here.

Comment: *"OP tried repeatedly to change it into an entirely different question"*, well well if *"Tell yo mama,..."* is a different question that the RFC 1350 doesn't defines.